# Trouble Redirecting inside a function

Tags: javascript, function, redirect

I have a simple animation I found online and modified to fit my needs, but no matter what I try, I cannot get it to redirect after the animation is done. If I remove the setTimeout It redirects immediately without showing the animation. This is my code:

```
<html>
<head>
<div id="x" style="background-color:rgb(10,10,10)" align="center">
<img src="icon.ico" alt="Icon" height="256px">
</div>
<script>
    var unBlue=105;
    var gEvent=setInterval("toWhite();", 10);
    var redirect=1;
    function toWhite(){
        if(unBlue<200) document.getElementById("x").style.backgroundColor="rgb("+unBlue+",30,30)";
        else clearInterval(gEvent)
        unBlue+=1;
        setTimeout(myFunction, 1000);
        location.redirect("home.html") //doesn't work
    }
</script>
</html>
```

I'm still getting used to javascript so a full explanation would be much appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: is `myFunction()` defined?

Comment: "a full explanation" would be nice from you too. "it doesn't work" is just about the least helpful thing you could say.. what errors are you getting, etc?

Comment: as i said, "I cannot get it to redirect after the animation". please read the whole paragraph next time. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this code snippet works for me...

first as suggested use `window.location.replace` instead of `location.redirect` which does not seem to be supported

second `myFunction` does not seem to be defined.. you didn't specify if it does anything so if you just want to delay - I put null instead

```
<html>
    <head>
        <div id="x" style="background-color:rgb(10,10,10)" align="center">
            <img src="icon.ico" alt="Icon" height="256px">
        </div>
    <script>
        var unBlue=105;
        var gEvent=setInterval("toWhite();", 10);
        var redirect=1;
        function toWhite(){
            if(unBlue<200) document.getElementById("x").style.backgroundColor="rgb("+unBlue+",30,30)";
            else clearInterval(gEvent)
            unBlue+=1;
            setTimeout(null, 1000);
            window.location.replace("http://stackoverflow.com")
         }
    </script>
</html>
```

Comment: surprisingly, whenever i change the "window.location.replace("http://stackoverflow.com")" to a html file not a website, it immediately redirects instead of waiting. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

you need something how this ,is not need use Jquery  :

For example:

```
// similar behavior as an HTTP redirect


    window.location.replace("http://example.com");

// similar behavior as clicking on a link

    window.location.href = "http://example.com";
```

more imformation :[here](http://here)

you code with the soluction :

```html
<html>
<head>
<div id="x" style="background-color:rgb(10,10,10)" align="center">
<img src="icon.ico" alt="Icon" height="256px">
</div>
<script>
    var unBlue=105;
    var gEvent=setInterval("toWhite();", 10);
    var redirect=1;
    function toWhite(){
        if(unBlue<200) document.getElementById("x").style.backgroundColor="rgb("+unBlue+",30,30)";
        else clearInterval(gEvent)
        unBlue+=1;
        setTimeout(myFunction, 1000);
        //location.redirect("home.html") //doesn't work
      window.location.href = "http://example.com";
    }
</script>
</html>
```